# Make vim show all the colors

Tags: colorscheme, terminal

I have a problem with making vim show a colorscheme fully (like in gvim). I've read about how to enable 256 color mode in terminal and it vim, but somehow it just doesn't work. The state of now is:

`:echo &t_Co` returns `256`

```
[~]$ tput colors
256
[~]$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Colortest shows all the colors:
[image: colortest]

But yet, vim doesn't show `grey20` color of the colorscheme, instead using the terminal background. I also tried changing it to `grey` without success:
[image: hi Normal]

The system is ubuntu 14.04. and the terminal gnome terminal, although I've tried with terminator and tmux, with no success.

Any idea what could gone wrong?

Comment: And just for the next guy looking for colortest.vim: `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/colortest.vim`

Answer (score 11):

The colorscheme must be missing `cterm` definitions, the full highlight command should look like:

```
hi Normal cterm=NONE ctermfg=15 ctermbg=7 gui=NONE guifg=White guibg=grey20
```

If your terminal supports 256 colors, you might need [color codes greater than 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xterm_256color_chart.svg).

If you have a *true color* terminal, you could add these settings instead to enable 24-bit compatibility:

```
set termguicolors

" Correct RGB escape codes for vim inside tmux
if !has('nvim') && $TERM ==# 'screen-256color'
  let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
  let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif
```

From the help for [`'termguicolors'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27termguicolors%27):

> Note that the `cterm` attributes are still used, not the `gui` ones.

Read more:

- [`:h highlight-args`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#highlight-args)
- [`:h cterm-colors`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#cterm-colors)
- [Vim Tip *256 colors in vim*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim)

Comment: Good, simple solution. You may need to use `tmux-256color` in your comparison, nowadays.